# Search SQL Server for duplicates after their original appearance

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, ssms

I have a file name, a smalldatetime stamp of that file, and a value contained within that file in a table in my database, each file has multiple values, but the file name and the timestamp will repeat for each value contained within that file in the table.

Here is what I need to do.

I must 1) find the earliest file that contained that value, and then 2) count how many times that value appears in other files, sum all those counts up, and then display a table that looks like the following.

```
    |   | FileName  | TimeStamp | Duplicates
    | 1 | file1.txt | first     | 30000
    | 2 | file2.txt | second    | 20000
```

etc

I must also format the table a second way, like this...

```
    |   | FileName  | file1.txt | file2.txt | file3.txt
    | 1 | file1.txt | NULL      | 15000     | 15000
    | 2 | file2.txt | NULL      | NULL      | 20000
    | 3 | file3.txt | NULL      | NULL      | NULL
```

any help would be appreciated

```
select FileName
    ,min(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
    ,count(Value) as Duplicates 
from Table with (nolock) 
where TimeStamp > min(TimeStamp) 
group by FileName 
having count(Value) > 1
```

the error I'm getting is

```
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 An aggregate may not appear in the 
   WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause 
   or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Comment: the query I tried was...

Comment: select FileName, min(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp, count(Value) as Duplicates from Table with (nolock)
where TimeStamp > min(TimeStamp)
group by FileName
having count(Value) > 1  -- the error I'm getting is Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: please add it to the question via the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to not have the aggregate in the where statement.
You may need to change the name of the timestamp, or just add it to the having statement.

Try this:

```
select FileName, 
min(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp,
count(Value) as Duplicates 
from Table with (nolock) 
group by FileName 
having count(Value) > 1 
and TimeStamp > min(TimeStamp)
```

Comment: this code doesn't run with the following error: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'Table.Timestamp' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
-- To fix it, I added TimeStamp to the group by clause, but then I returned 0 results which I know for a fact is inaccurate.

Comment: try to rename min(timestamp) as something other than timestamp.
This could be casusing an issue, because it thinks you are calling the table itself and not the aggregate rename.

Comment: Timestamp isn't the actual name of the field, I just renamed them to something generic to obfuscate the business data that those fields represent